# What are the benefits and drawbacks of NSPOF networks over SPOF ones?

Tags: network, networking, redundancy

NSPOF has redundant links and redundant network components, so I think the biggest benefit it has over SPOF is high fault tolerance and the biggest drawback is the high cost of buying and maintaining all that equipment. What other benefits and drawbacks are there? Which one has simpler administration or greater scalability?

Comment: Unfortunately, all "_education, certification, or homework+" questions are explicitly off-topic here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You summed it all up. A redundant network requires more hardware to build and more qualified staff to maintain. Obviously, a simpler network is easier to maintain.

By scalability, there isn't much difference, but a very large network that has hundreds of SPOF would be a nightmare. At the same time, a large, *entirely* redundant network would also be quite a feat, so practically you make a network redundant where it really matters (core, distribution) and leave the access layer and less important areas (with limited failure impact) mostly simple.